# builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python-3.x

The question is:
Write a function `get_column(game, col_num)` that takes a legal 3 x 3 game of noughts and crosses as explained above and returns a 3-element list containing the values from column number col_num, top to bottom. You may assume col_num is in the range 0 to 2 inclusive.
Hint: Since noughts and crosses is always played on a 3 x 3 grid, you don't need to handle general n x m grids. It is sufficient to just explicitly select the row and column elements you need, so you don't actually require a loop for this question. However, you're welcome to try using a loop to give yourself more practice.

Hence I want to retrieve any column which I mention in the function from a list of list.

Below code is what I tried

```
def get_column(game, col_num):
    """returns a 3-element list containing the values from column number 
    col_num, top to bottom"""
    j = col_num
    result = []
    for i in game:
        result.append(game[i][j])
    return result
```

Comment: Unable to add these points in above question that I posted. hence adding here

board = [['O', 'X', 'O'],
         ['X', ' ', ' '],
         ['X', ' ', ' ']]
column1 = get_column(board, 0)
print(column1)


Expected answer is : ['0','x','x']

but I am getting the error as:
"builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list" please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to solve your exercise for you, but I can tell you why you are getting the error.

Your loop

```
for i in game:
```

Loops through the 3x3 list of lists. So it will loop 3 times, namely

```
i = ['O', 'X', 'O']         # pass 1
i = ['X', '','']            # pass 2
i = ['X', '','']            # pass 3
```

So i is a list. You are then trying to use i to index a list in this statement

```
result.append(game[i][j])
```

but lists must be indexed with a single integer (o, 1 or 2), or a slice(like 0:1, 1:2, etc).

Comment: Thanks @Deepstop, This is still not working:----------------------------------------------def diagonals(game):
    """ """
    result= []
    for i in range(len(game)):
        j = i
        result.append(game[i][j])
        return result

Comment: @Manju this is a different function, and it returns the diagonal from top left to bottom right of the board without error. So your original question about the error has been answered. If you want to fix the function in your original question, then apply the for i  in range(len(game)) loop from your comment to the get_column function. If you are having trouble with something else, please ask another question.